# Purchase order number to fulfil customer order number - SQL

Tags: sql

| order | Qty | Inventory | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | -1 | -1 | Customer Order |
| 1002 | -1 | -2 | Customer Order |
| 1003 | -1 | -3 | Customer Order |
| 1004 | -1 | -4 | Customer Order |
| 1005 | -5 | -9 | Customer Order |
| 1006 | **3** | -6 | **Purchase Order** |
| 1007 | **6** | 0 | **Purchase Order** |

With the above table, can we find the purchase order number that would fulfil customer order. 

Example:

| order # | Qty | Inventory | Type | Purchase order # that will fulfil order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | -1 | -1 | Customer Order | 1006 |
| 1002 | -1 | -2 | Customer Order | 1006 |
| 1003 | -1 | -3 | Customer Order | 1006 |
| 1004 | -1 | -4 | Customer Order | 1007 |
| 1005 | -5 | -9 | Customer Order | 1007 |
| 1006 | 3 | -6 | Purchase Order |  |
| 1007 | 6 | 0 | Purchase Order |  |

**SQL**

```
SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN Inventory >= 0 THEN OrderNumber
               ELSE LEAD(CASE WHEN QTY > 0 THEN OrderNumber END) IGNORE NULLS
                    OVER(ORDER BY OrderNumber)
          END PurchaseOrderNoToFulfil
FROM OrderTable;
```

The above query does not keep track of the purchase order that have already been used. Example, it shows purchase order # 1006 for both customer order # 1004 and 1005. Since only 3 Qty were available for 1006, it satisfies upto order 1003, but not beyond that.

For more context:
On order 1001, the inventory is -1 (oversold). Order 1002, the inventory is -2 and so on. On order 1006, there is an incoming purchase order of Qty 3 to fulfil the previous customer orders. But the quantity of 3 can only fulfil upto order 1003. Order 1004 and 1005 will have to wait until 1007 PO comes in.

Comment: Please add the query you have so far and where you are having trouble.

Comment: SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN Inventory >= 0 THEN OrderNumber
               ELSE LEAD(CASE WHEN QTY > 0 THEN OrderNumber END) IGNORE NULLS
                    OVER(ORDER BY OrderNumber)
          END PurchaseOrderNoToFulfil
FROM OrderTable;

Comment: I still don't understand what the rules/assumptions are here.

Comment: On order 1001, the inventory is -1 (oversold). Order 1002, the inventory is -2 and so on. On order 1006, there is an incoming purchase order of Qty 3 to fulfil the previous customer orders. But the quantity of 3 can only fulfil upto order 1003. Order 1004 and 1005 will have to wait until 1007 PO comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is giving me results in line with what you're asking for. Perhaps you'll find it useful.

```
with C as (
    select ordernum, -inventory as inventory,
        sum(-qty) over (order by ordernum) as fulfilled
    from O where "Type" = 'Customer Order'
), P as (
    select *, sum(qty) over (order by ordernum) as POed
    from O where "Type" = 'Purchase Order')
select ordernum, inventory, PO, POed
from C outer apply (
    select min(ordernum) as PO, min(POed) as POed from P where POed >= fulfilled
) oa
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=25a4efd31efc0827940a83b8658eb2b2

Rewritten with a scalar subquery:

```
with C as (
    select ordernum, -inventory as inventory,
        sum(-qty) over (order by ordernum) as fulfilled
    from O where "Type" = 'Customer Order'
), P as (
    select *, sum(qty) over (order by ordernum) as POed
    from O where "Type" = 'Purchase Order')
select ordernum, inventory,
    (select min(ordernum) as PO from P where POed >= fulfilled) as PO
from C
```

Comment: Hi, Snowflake does not support 'outer apply'. Is there a alternative for the 'outer apply'. Thanks.

Comment: @rain_maker Probably just turn it into a scalar subquery (as above.) I removed the second column that you probably didn't really need anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive orders as (
   select row_number() over (order by `order`) o, * from ords
),
cte(id, r_id, s) as (
    select min(o.o), o1.o, o.qty + o1.qty from orders o 
    join orders o1 on o1.qty + o.qty >= 0 where o.qty < 0 and o1.qty = (select min(o2.qty) from orders o2 where o2.qty > 0)
    union all
    select c.id + 1, case when c.s + o1.qty >= 0 or o3.o is null then c.r_id else o3.o end, 
        case when c.s + o1.qty >= 0 then c.s + o1.qty else c.s + o1.qty + o3.qty end 
    from cte c join orders o1 on c.id + 1 = o1.o 
    left join orders o3 on o3.o > c.r_id where c.id + 1 <= (select max(o2.o) from orders o2 where o2.qty < 0)
)
select o.*, c.r_id from orders o left join cte c on o.o = c.id
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I get the below error though.  SQL compilation error: [O1.O] is not a valid group by expression